# How to SUM with condition when grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a list of rows, and I'd like to SUM the number of the lines when grouping (a sort of COUNT) but only when, for each row, the field **customField=0**.

Example :

```
title       customField
aaa         1
aaa         0
bbb         0
ccc         1
bbb         1
aaa         0
```

So, the output should be :

```
aaa 2
bbb 1
ccc 0
```

How can I do it with MySql?

**EDIT**

In fact my real Query is this one :

```
SELECT forum_categories.title, COUNT(forum_topics.id) AS total_topics, COUNT(forum_messages.id) AS total_replies, MAX(forum_messages.date) AS last_message
FROM forum_categories
JOIN forum_topics ON forum_topics.category_id = forum_categories.id 
JOIN forum_messages ON forum_messages.topic_id = forum_topics.id
GROUP BY forum_categories.id ORDER BY forum_categories.date
```

And I have to count `COUNT(forum_messages.id) AS total_replies` only when `forum_messages.original=0`, that's why I request the SUM :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just filter the result set to exclude `customField=1`, i.e.

```
  SELECT title, COUNT(*) AS numTitle
    FROM yourtable
   WHERE customField = 0
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY numTitle DESC
```

Result:

```
aaa 2
bbb 1
```

To show all titles, including those which have a 0 count: (also helpful if other countings are needed)

```
  SELECT title
       , SUM(CASE WHEN customField=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numTitle
    FROM yourtable
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY numTitle DESC
```

Result:

```
aaa 2
bbb 1
ccc 0
```

More compact (but works only in MYSQL):

```
  SELECT title
       , SUM(customField=0) AS numTitle
    FROM yourtable
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY numTitle DESC
```

Comment: Not quite sure I follow then. You could use a `CASE` in the `SUM`, so like `SELECT title, SUM(CASE WHEN customField=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`... ?

Comment: Yeah seems to work! Thanks @ypercube : with the suggestion on the comments, it is show too ;)